# Plant coming up under creeping junipers and in other parts of perennial gardens

Tags: identification

As I said above I just noticed shoots of plants coming up throughout my garden.  They are a red color tip attached to very long bright green/yellow roots.  Would like to know what this is and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Include some photos? That description could be nearly any nuisance.

Comment: Knowing where you are in the world might help too, also a description of the any leaves you can see. At the moment its making me think of one of the Euphorbias, but that's something which pops up in the UK, so may well not be that at all.

Comment: Do you need help adding a photo?  Click 'edit' under the question, then it's the sixth button from the left (it looks like a little picture frame).  You can either upload a photo from your computer, or if you've already uploaded it to a photo sharing site like Imgur or Flickr, you can enter a link instead.

Comment: I am still waiting for pictures! Bamboo's got my vote for Euphorbias...but we still have to have more info!!!

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.